# Web Socket terminating prematurely

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I have been trying to connect to the `skinport` WebSocket using Python. The socket documentation is at the bottom of [this link](https://docs.skinport.com/?javascript--nodejs#salefeed). I am using `websocket-client` module for making a connection but the connection closes prematurely. Below is my code so far.

```
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, b, c):
    print("Connection closed")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Connection opened")
    ws.send("Hello, Server!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://skinport.com/saleFeed?app_id=730&currency=EUR",
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

I get the following traces/messages on the console

> --- request header --- GET /saleFeed?app_id=730&currency=EUR HTTP/1.1 Upgrade: websocket Host: skinport.com Origin: https://skinport.com
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: G9bSTZyU7TP2SQIOZgbbgg== Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
> Connection: Upgrade
>
> ---
>
> --- response header --- HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 10 Apr 2023 11:16:12 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding:
> chunked Connection: keep-alive CF-Ray: 7b5a9387bebd6bfd-SIN
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0 Expires:
> -1 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload Via: 1.1 vegur CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
> Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
> 'unsafe-inline' https://platform.twitter.com
> https://syndication.twitter.com https://www.googletagmanager.com
> https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com https://www.google.com
> https://www.google-analytics.com https://maps.googleapis.com
> https://apis.google.com https://connect.facebook.net
> https://challenges.cloudflare.com
> https://static.cloudflareinsights.com https://bat.bing.com;report-uri
> https://o298045.ingest.sentry.io/api/5193335/security/?sentry_key=98577efcbca24e6daef4a099b6611076
> Expect-Ct: max-age=0 Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?1 Pragma: no-cache
> Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
> X-Download-Options: noopen X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none X-Xss-Protection: 0
> Set-Cookie:
> __cf_bm=kin41Kk7yGk9NxwTBggN4_Ga4scFC2391h_Ggv5rVeQ-1681125372-0-Ae23hoR65z9NdcPVYOlSk2y5PTPe9WtzqBTlWG1NvjVHoD5bac7WaPISitKfUEnLizFf45QQFxKbMurf47/I/rs=;
> path=/; expires=Mon, 10-Apr-23 11:46:12 GMT; domain=.skinport.com;
> HttpOnly; Secure Server: cloudflare
> ----------------------- Handshake status 200 OK - goodbye Handshake status 200 OK Connection closed

I don't understand why the connection is closed without the messages being exchanged. The `on_message` function is never called during the process.

Answer (score 0):

The websocket connection endpoint is `wss://skinport.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`

You also need to make sure to send the message `40` after you connect. In my experience the server will close the connection if you give it anything unexpected (this includes the `Hello Server!` message in the `on_open` callback), so just make sure to mimic what you see in your browser's dev tools.

Here is a working example for subscribing to the listings feed:

```
from time import sleep
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, b, c):
    print("Connection closed")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Connection opened")
    ws.send("40")

    sleep(1)

    ws.send('42["saleFeedJoin",{"appid":730,"currency":"EUR","locale":"en"}]')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://skinport.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket",
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```